# ffmpeg segment command adds black frame

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I'm going through a problem that I cannot solve with the ffmpeg segment command.

I need to split a video in multiple chunks, and I am trying the following:

`ffmpeg -i input.mov -c copy -an -map 0 -segment_time 30 -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 output_%%03d.mov -y`

This works fine, until I compare the first chunk to the original video.

Apparently ffmpeg is adding a black frame in front of it, and I can't figure out why.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you cut at arbitrary times without reencoding, (`-c copy`) then the output segments can miss some needed frames, which are replaced by black frames. So either you reencode the segments, or you drop `-segment_time`: in the latter case ffmpeg will cut the video at keyframe boundaries, but the segments will have different lengths.

Comment: @PierU thank you very much for your reply. I tried to remove -segment_time but it still added a black frame in front it. Full command: `ffmpeg -i video.mov -map 0 -f segment -reset_timestamps 1 output.mov -threads 32` I am desperate :(

Comment: @PierU Got closer! With the following command I still get a black frame, but when I concatenate them everything seems fine apart for the first frame being duplicated: `ffmpeg -i input.mov -an -codec copy -map 0:v? -force_key_frames 1 -reset_timestamps 1 -f segment output.mov -y
`